# AWS Cloudformation created role not showing in identitypool dropdown

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I've created a cloudformation template by using Troposphere.  I am however stuck on attaching a role to the identity pool.

Both the role and identitypool was created fine - but the role attachement doesn't work.

So I tried to attach the role on the AWS UI, but it doesn't appear in the dropdown next to "Authenticated role".

[image: This section]

**This is the trust relationship I am using:**

```
 {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "<<REGION:GUID>>"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What should I do to get the role to display in the dropdown?

Would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: You should post the relevant parts of your CloudFormation template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the role to display in the dropdown, you need to add a **RoleName** property.

The problem was never regarding the trust relationship.  The problem was in the way it was defined in the CloudFormation template.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-rolename

Answer (score 0):

In my case, we have AWS account for development, with hundreds of roles (I believe around 1500) mostly because of nobody cleaning them up. The select field probably does not have an infinite loader, maybe some search would be sufficient, but what helped me was to prefix role with 0 to get it sorted at the beginning.